# No suitable driver found when connected to mysql in groovy

Tags: mysql, jdbc, groovy

```
    import com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
    import com.mysql.jdbc.*
    import groovy.sql.*

    /*  the commented code works fine

    MysqlDataSource ds = new MysqlDataSource()
    ds.user = 'root'
    ds.password = ""
    ds.url = 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test'

    Sql sql=Sql.newInstance(ds)

    sql.close()
    */
    d=Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance()
    println d.class // class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver


    Sql sql=Sql.newInstance(
    'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test',
    'root',
     "",
    'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
    )
```

the code commented works fine and I can get the instance of Driver
But when I use the

```
     Sql sql=Sql.newInstance(
     'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test',
     'root',
      "",
     'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
     )
```

it throws a exception:
`java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test`
I can not fix it ,is there anyboy coming to help me?

Comment: How are you adding the driver to the classpath?

Comment: @tim_yates I use the groovyConsole and use the "`add jar(s) to classpath`" command . adding "`@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader = true)
@Grab(group='mysql', module='mysql-connector-java', version='5.1.27')`" to the code will solve the problem but I still don't know why...

Comment: Because the JDBC driver management in Java looks at the system classloader for the JDBC jars.  So you either need to use the `@GrabConfig`, or you need to start the console with the jar on the classpath, ie: `groovyconsole -cp  mysql-connector-java-5.1.27-bin.jar`.  I don't think there's a way to tell the `add jars to path` option to use the systemClassLoader :-(

Comment: @tim_yates Yes,just like what you said,Thx ^_^.

Comment: Added as an answer :-)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The JDBC driver management in Java looks at the system classloader for the JDBC jars.

So to run a mysql accessing script in the GroovyConsole, you either need to use:

```
@GrabConfig( systemClassLoader=true )
@Grab( 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.27' )
```

in your script, or you need to start the console with the jar on the classpath by running it with:

```
groovyconsole -cp mysql-connector-java-5.1.27-bin.jar
```

I don't think there's a way to tell the add jars to path option to use the systemClassLoader :-(

Comment: Nice. Got the same problem here, and now it's OK !

Comment: Thanks - also works with MariaDB client, eg. 'org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:2.2.3'.  However... I find that running the self-contained script (not Gradle) at a (Cygwin) prompt I do need it... but that in Eclipse I don't need this `@GrabConfig` thing, and indeed that including it causes this error: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed: General error during conversion: No suitable ClassLoader found for grab"... Grrr...